# How to mock react navigation navigate function with callback in jest

Tags: javascript, react-native, mocking, jestjs, react-navigation

I'm trying to test my functional component using jest:

```
const MyComponent = props => {

  const myFunction = () => {
      const { navigation, onIndexChange } = props;

      navigation.navigate("Modal", {
          onGoBack: () => {
              onIndexChange(0);
          }
      });
  };

  ...
}
```

Now in my test if I run

```
expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

it perfectly passes. But I don't know how to mock `navigate` so that I can test it with `toHaveBeenCalledWith`, basically I want something like this:

```
expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Modal", {onGoBack: onIndexChange(0)});
```

This is how I have mocked it currently:

```
const navigation = {
    navigate: jest.fn()
};
```

and this is what I get when I try to use toHaveBeenCalledWith:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your assertion

```
expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Modal", {onGoBack: onIndexChange(0)});
```

means that you expect `navigation.navigate` to have been called as a second an object with `onGoBack` which has a value of the result of `onIndexChange` called with `0`

but in your implementation the value of `onGoBack` is an anonymous function

so if you can assert that the function has been called with an object with function:

```
expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Modal", {
  onGoBack: expect.any(Function)
});
```

and whenever that function is called it will call the given onIndexChange

```
describe('whenever the anonymous function is called', () => {
  let onGoBack;
  beforeAll(() => {
    const [firstCall] = navigation.navigate.mock.calls;
    [location, { onGoBack }] = firstCall;
    onGoBack()
  })

  it('should call onIndexChange', () => {
    expect(onIndexChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0);
  });
});
```

[**working example** (without React)](https://repl.it/repls/IndelibleRawVoxels)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that and now it says: -   expected: "onGoBack": [Function mockConstructor],   but received: "onGoBack": [Function onGoBack],